# Which transformation in frequency domain equals a x-axis shift of a signal in time domain?

Tags: fourier-transform

I have discrete Fourier transformation results from measurements. Looking at the signal from the time domain perspective, I want to shift the signal on the $x$-axis to the left or right.

Which transformation in the frequency-domain results in a left/right shift in the time-domain?

Comment: This question belongs on dsp.SE, not on stats.SE. Please ask the moderators to migrate it there. You can contact the moderators by clicking on the `flag` link below your question.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, i did send a message to moderators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $s(t)$ is your signal in time domain, you want to make the operation $s(t+\Delta t)$, which according to the [Fourier's transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) properties, is equivalent to the operation :
$$
S(f)e^{j2\pi f\Delta t}
$$
$S(f)$ being $s(t)$ Fourier's transform.

In case of a [discrete Fourier's transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform), which is defined as 
$$
S[k] = \sum^{N-1}_{n=0}{s[n]e^{\frac{-i2\pi kn}{N}}}
$$ 
with $s$ the signal and N the number of points of both signal and DFT.

The operation to be applied in order to induce a shift by a number c of samples to $s[n]$ and obtain $s[n+c]$ is :
$$
e^{\frac{-i2\pi kc}{N}}S[k]
$$

Which in matlab code would be done with :

```
exp(-j*2*pi*(1:(N-1))*c/N).*S_fdt;
```

Comment: What's the problem, downvoter ?

Comment: Perhaps you could restrict to the case of discrete time and discrete Fourier transform (not the downvoter)